# cors access-control-allow-origin * credentials true

Tags: cors, wildcard, credentials

I set up global CORS in Spring Boot, and I wrote the following code, and found that if access-control-allow-origin is *, credentials can not be true. Why can not credentials be true and why does CORS work if it does not?

```java
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){
        registry.addMapping("/api/bbs/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's the way CORS was designed.

However...

You can easily simply 'mirror back' the value of the Origin Request header in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

So you effectively send back this response header:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <value-of-Origin-request-header>`

That is equally as 'global' as specifying `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'd like to ask you one more question, what does the word mirror back mean? I am not yet familiar with English and it is difficult to understand the exact meaning.

Comment: I meant that whatever value is passed in the Origin request header should be returned EXACTLY in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. So if the request includes this header `Origin: https://www.yoursite.com:9001` than you should respond with this response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.yoursite.com:9001`. Like a mirror reflecting a value back... :)